# Use mysql command line interface with memcached

Tags: mysql, command-line, memcached

I'm trying to test the performance of using memcached on a MySQL server to improve performance.

I want to be able to use the normal MySQL command line, but I can't seem to get it to connect to memcached, even when I specify the right port.

I'm running the MySQL command on the same machine as both the memcached process and the MySQL server.

I've looked around online, but I can't seem to find anything about using memcached other than with program APIs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Memcached has its own protocol.  The MySQL client cannot connect directly to a memcached server.

You may be thinking of the MySQL 5.6 feature that allows MySQL server to respond to connections using a memcached-compatible protocol, and read and write directly to InnoDB tables.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html

But this does not allow MySQL clients to connect to memcached -- it's the opposite, allowing memcached clients to connect to mysqld.

---

Re your comment:

The InnoDB memcached interface is not really a caching solution per se, it's a solution for using a familiar key/value API for persistent data in InnoDB tables.  InnoDB does do transparent caching of data pages in its buffer pool, but this is no different from conventional data reads with SQL.  InnoDB also commits all changes to its transaction log synchronously on commit.

Here's a blog from my colleague at Percona.  He tested whether the MySQL 5.6 memcached API could be used as a caching layer, and found that actually using memcached is still superior.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/03/29/mysql-5-6-innodb-memcached-plugin-as-a-caching-layer/

Here's one conclusion from that blog:

> As expected, there is a slowdown for write operations when using the InnoDB version.  But there is also a slight increase in the average fetch time.

Comment: Ok, I see. Would that compatibility layer just allow clients to use the memcached API, or would it also allow for the memcached server to sit on top of mysql and actually do caching?